# Split a file into several small files

Tags: perl

I have a code that allows me to treat a file, in which he seeks all line starting with "false" and return them to me.
I would like each line with "false" is stored in the file, namely.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
open(DATA, '<', 'DATA.csv');
my @a = <DATA>;
my @b = grep(/false/, @a);
chomp(@b);
for (my $i=0; $i <= $#b; $i++) {
    print $i + 1;
    print ". ";
    print split('false',"$b[$i]\n");
}
```

__________________DATA____________________________________

```
    2015.07.23  16:47:23
                  false,    false,       true,      false,    true,    false,
          defau,  ame_a,    ame_m,       ame_uc,     ame_f,    ams_l,  en_affi,
    true  DPA01,  fault,    fault,       fault,      fault,    fault,      1,
    false DPA02,  dfgeh,         ,            ,           ,    fault,      1,
    true  DPA03,  fault,    fault,         olt,      fault,    fault,      1,
    false DPA01,  fault,       at,       fault,          2,    fault,      1,
    false DPA02,  dfgeh,         ,            ,           ,    fault,      1,
    true  DPA03,  fault,    fault,         olt,      fault,    fault,      1,
```

___DPA02___________________

```
dfgeh



fault
1
```

___DPA01________________

```
fault
at
fault
2
fault
1
```

___DPA02_____________

```
dfgeh



fault
1
```

Comment: What your code is doing is not at all what you are describing. It's not clear what the output you show (rather the several outputs) are supposed to mean. Please [edit] your question and try to describe the problem you are facing. Also, you are not looking for lines that start with `false`. You get the lines that _contain_ `false` anywhere in the line. There is a difference.

Comment: @Paul: How are you creating two files with same name? Are you creating on different path?

Comment: You need to clean up the language in your questions. You should also refer to your previous questions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725457/how-to-build-a-file-splitter-in-perl), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688466/compare-2-file-line-and-column).. Each time you use a different user name..it is not good style.. You have also posted a very similar question with username `Serge` but maybe you have deleted that one? The main problem with your questions is the English language. It is very difficult to understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

1. Read a line from the CSV file.
2. If it starts with 'false':

   1. Extract all the columns.
   2. Open a file using the content of column 2 as the name.
   3. Write the rest of the items on the line to that file, one item per line.

The program you have there won't do that at all.

I first suggest, use the Text::CSV module from CPAN if you want to safely process CSV files. If you do that, the process becomes a lot simpler:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
open my $csv_file, "<", "DATA.csv" or die "Can't open CSV file: $!\n";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($csv_file)) {
    # First item is significator plus filename.
    my($significator_and_file) = clean($row->[0]);
    my ($significator, $file) = split /\s+/, $significator_and_file;
    next unless $significator and $significator eq 'false';

    open my $per_line_fh, ">>", $file or die "Can't open per-line file $file: $!\n";

    # One item per line, plus final newline.
    shift @$row;
    print $per_line_fh join "\n", map { clean($_) } @$row;
    print $per_line_fh "\n";
    close $per_line_fh;
}

sub clean {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Joe McMahon, that sounds like a stupid question, I tried your code and searched for what you may have forgotten, unfortunately I get no files.

Comment: Edited to clean up the rather messy data format. The extra spaces in the data as you have in your example have to be cleaned off to allow the data to be compared against and used properly. The combination of true/false and the filename is particularly a pain.

Comment: perfect, McMahon Thank